# Does djv JSON schema validation library work for JSON Arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, jsonschema

I tried using [djv](https://github.com/korzio/djv#readme) library in my javascript project and while it works for `JSON Objects` validation, I can't get it to work with `JSON Arrays`. Has anyone tried it before? Do you know any other library that can be used as a JSON schema validator on the client side?

Comment: What exactly is not working with JSON arrays?

Comment: This is another option https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4

Comment: I use `validate(name: String, object: Object) -> error: String` function but it seems to work only for json objects.

Comment: several other options here: https://github.com/ebdrup/json-schema-benchmark